# Database Transactions in Application Services as defined by Domain-Driven Design

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

In the book "Implementing Domain-Driven Design" by Vaughn Vernon it is said on page 120 that

> Application Services reside in the Application Layer. [...]. They may control persistence transactions [...]".

[image]

1. Now, the Controller in a MVC application is an application service, right?
2. If yes, does it mean that the controller can commit or roll back a database transaction (directly or indirectly, but through a mecanism that the controller can manage)?

Comment: Controllers provide access to application services via HTTP. Application services may also be accessed via console. Inside controllers, I instantiate application services, and execute them.

Comment: I agree with @Geoffrey. In case your MVC Controller receives an HTTP Request or is bound to some particular execution context (e.g., HTTP) then it belongs an Infrastructure Layer. The Controller in MVC does typically read the Request e.g. `ServerRequestInterface` thus, IMO it is more appropriate to extract the application logic into a Service or Command Handler that is context agnostic. The Controller then has the Service or CommandBus as a dependency, and is responsible for building an (e.g.,) Input DTO from the HTTP Request, passing it to the Application Service and returning a Response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view Controllers as Application Services, especially in simple applications, but it might be a better idea to have dedicated objects for these services because :

- Controller is a UI concept. You might want to change or add a UI layer and still keep the applicative scenarios intact without rewriting them.
- Orchestrating calls to Repositories, domain entities and services plus carrying out applicative transactions might be too much responsibility for a Controller that is already in charge of dealing with View data and View navigation. See the Fat Controller antipattern.

Comment: I'd also add that application service methods are much more reusable when not hidden in controllers.

Comment: Why not put those commit and rollback calls in the commands (CQRS) themselves?

Comment: @Flavius A command is a simple DTO, a command handler usually is an application service.